# Why does someInputElement.type = 'button'; fail in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I'm stuck trying to get the following javascript to work in IE:

```
var lastMonthBn = document.createElement('input');
td.appendChild(lastMonthBn);
lastMonthBn.value='<';
lastMonthBn.type = 'button'; // Fails in IE
lastMonthBn.setAttribute('type','button'); // Also fails in IE
```

For some reason, i cannot set the input to a button, it fails. Works in chrome and firefox. So i'm a little confused and haven't had any luck trying to get it working.

I've isolated it to those lines by using alert()'s.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IE, you need to set up the button first, before adding it to the document. I.e.:

```
var lastMonthBn = document.createElement('input');
lastMonthBn.value='<';
lastMonthBn.type = 'button';

td.appendChild(lastMonthBn); // put this last
```

Comment: I think also i need to set the type before setting the value.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be the reason? From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536389(v=VS.85).aspx

> You must perform a second step when you use createElement to create the input element.
>   The createElement method generates an input text box, because that is the default input
>   type property. To insert any other kind of input element, first invoke createElement for
>   input, and then set the type property to the appropriate value in the next line of code.